# Муж матери — отчим

Tags: этимология, значение-слов, синонимы

Вопроса два. Основной — этимология слова *отчим*. Если встречалась убедительная версия, прошу поделиться. Попутный вопрос о значении и синонимах к слову: муж матери = неродной отец?

Как я понимаю, односложных синонимов нет, и это одна странность. Главная же состоит в неопределённости отношений неродных (взрослых и детей), когда возраст и статус последних позволяют им быть независимыми от жизни опекунов — самим иметь жён и мужей. Когда же повторный (следующий) брак матери случается после их собственного, то разве не странно им будет относиться к её мужу, как к неродному отцу? Следует ли из этого, что только фактом усыновления фиксируется это слово — *отчим* — и тогда в его этимологии это должно отражаться?

Answer (score 2):

[**отчим**](http://rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/dictionary/popular-rus/fc/slovar-206-2.htm#zag-2379), -а, *м*.
Неродной отец, муж матери по отношению к ее детям от прежнего брака.

Этимология:
Образовано от ***отец*** с помощью суф. ***-имъ***.
(Популярный словарь русского языка. Толково-энциклопедический. — М.: Русский язык-Медиа. А. П. Гуськова, Б. В.Сотин. 2003.)

**Синонимы**: ***вотчим*** (рег., прост.), **отец**; нечасто встречается ***названный отец, социальный отец***.

[Юридическая формулировка другая (и я с ней согласна): отчимом является мужчина, который вступил в брак с женщиной, имеющей детей. Сыновья и дочери женщины, внебрачные или родившиеся в предыдущем браке, являются по отношению к новому мужу пасынками или падчерицами.
В моей практике были случаи, когда мужчина женился на матери-одиночке и становился *отчимом собственному биологическому ребенку* (по закону).]

А этимологическая версия встретилась такая.
Современное значение русского слова *отчим* — неродной отец;
в украинском языке — ВIТЧИ́М;
в белорусском языке — АЙЧЫ́М (от слова АЙЦÉЦ, отец);
в польских диалектах — OJCIM, OCYM.

*Отчим* образовано от слова *отец*, а точнее — от его форм: древнерусская форма *ОТЬЦЬ*, современная основа *ОТЧ-* в словах *отчий*, *отчизна*, форма звательного падежа *ОТЧЕ*.
К этой основе *ОТЧ-* и был добавлен словообразующий элемент *-ИМ*.
Можно ли считать *-ИМ* суффиксом? — вопрос спорный.
Суффикс *-ИМ* есть в русском языке, но он имеет совершенно другие значения:
любить – любИМый, ранить – ранИМый.
Кроме того, есть ещё и глагольное окончание *-ИМ*: мы любИМ, мы ходИМ, мы летИМ.

В Дополнительном списке биконсонантных корней находим такой пункт:
JM [jem, im] — мои невзгоды; идея обременённости чем-либо.
*ОТЕЦ + ИМ =* …суровый для меня отец; отец, под бременем которого мне тяжело жить.
  [**ОТЧИМ — не очень приятное слово**](http://literra.listbb.ru/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=3455)

Для многих мужчин ***родным*** считается тот ребенок, которого они (*в качестве отца*) воспитали и вырастили, передали ему свое отношение к окружающему миру, сделали его как бы продолжением себя.

Comment: Очевидно, слово уникально по форме привлечённого «словообразующего элемента» и по смыслу незаслуженно «неприятному» (вдовой солдата добровольно не становятся). По редкостному своему строению может соперничать разве что со словом ПУТЬ, и тоже отглагольное в конце — имать, иметь.

Answer (score 2):

Имена собственные: Анисим, Вадим, Герасим, Евдоким, Никодим, Трофим и проч., оканчиваются на «им». Возможно, что это самое «им» означает «имя», точно так же как «ним» в терминах: антоним, этноним, патроним…
По аналоги «отчим» - (отец+имя), т.е. именующийся отцом или названый отец, а так же «побратим» - именующийся братом или названный брат.
В словаре Шанского Н.М.: Побрати́м. Общеслав. Суф. -преф. производное (по- — -им) от брат.